# jquery .glow method does not work properly in Firefox

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 3 different products being displayed in my page. Each product should have a different glow color. The code I use is below

```
 $('.yellow').on('mouseenter', function () {
            $(this).glow({ radius: "20", color: "#D7CD3A" });
        })
        .on('mouseout', function () {
            $(this).glow({ radius: "20", color: "#D7CD3A", disable: true });
        });

        $('.purple').on('mouseenter', function () {
            $(this).glow({ radius: "20", color: "#a354bb" });
        })
        .on('mouseout', function () {
            $(this).glow({ radius: "30", color: "#a354bb", disable: true });
        });

        $('.green').on('mouseenter', function () {
            $(this).glow({ radius: "30", color: "#538b73" });
        })
        .on('mouseout', function () {
            $(this).glow({ radius: "20", color: "#538b73", disable: true });
        });
```

In Chrome, this is perfectly working fine. I just came to know that this is not supported in IE, but in Firefox, it only taking the first product glow color which I would highlight.

For ex, when I hover purple product, then purple hover color is displayed. Then when I hover on yellow product, again the same purple glow color is displayed whereas it should be displaying yellow glow color.

Am I going wrong somewhere? or Is this a bug in Firefox?

Kinldy help

You can check it  [here](http://udowalzfinal.umatechcorner.com) , Scroll down, the products would be displayed

UPDATED:
I changed my code like this according to #ProllyGeek suggestions

```
var glowm;
$('.yellow').on('mouseover', function () {
            glowm = $(this).glow({ radius:"20", color: "#D7CD3A" });
        })
        .on('mouseout', function () {
            //$(this).glow({ radius: "20", color: "#D7CD3A", disable: true });
            glowm.remove();

        });
```

Now I see that glowm is "undefined". I don't understand why. This however works fine in Chrome. But not in Firefox..

I need to reset color css property. This is where I am currently stuck. Someone pls pls help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I set ID attribute to all the img tags & referred to this #id in javascript. The code is written like the below now.

```
$('#yellow1').on('mouseenter', function () {
            $(this).glow({ radius: "20", color: "#D7CD3A" });
        })
        .on('mouseout', function () {
            //$(this).glow({ radius: "20", color: "#D7CD3A", disable: true });
            $(this).glow({ disable: true });
        });
```

I did this for every img tag used.

Answer (score 0):

> "JQMIGRATE: jQuery.browser is deprecated"

check this out :

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/blob/master/warnings.md#jqmigrate-jquerybrowser-is-deprecated

Comment: Do you suggest me to find the userAgent and then disable glow? But I want glow to work in Firefox perfectly. How can I achieve glow in Firefox? I don't wish to disable it.

Comment: Use css glow instead like one here :http://webdesign.about.com/od/css3tutorials/ss/css3-glow-effects.htm

Comment: Hi, http://jsfiddle.net/WYHmp/5/ I got this url from another stackoverflow post. I tried to do the samething in fact, but it returns the object as "undefined". So I am not sure where I am going wrong!!#